# ElasticSearch RestHighLevelClient re-connect on connection reset

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, resthighlevelclient

I am using Spring + RestHighLevelClient to send data to Elasticsearch

```
restHighLevelClient.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT)
```

But when the system has been idle for a while, the following exception is thrown

```
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer,
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.extractAndWrapCause(RestClient.java:828) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.6.2.jar!/:7.6.2],
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:248) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.6.2.jar!/:7.6.2],
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:235) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.6.2.jar!/:7.6.2],
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1514) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.6.2.jar!/:7.6.2],
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1484) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.6.2.jar!/:7.6.2],
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1454) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.6.2.jar!/:7.6.2],
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.search(RestHighLevelClient.java:970) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.6.2.jar!/:7.6.2],
```

Is it possible to configure somehow to re-connect in case connection is rest?